# Initialize the protected static member from the subclass

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I want to know if it's possible to initialize a protected static member from the subclass.
For example,

```
// head file
class Test
{
protected:
    static int i;
};
class Test2 : public Test{};

//cpp file
#include "headfile.h"
int Test2::i = 1;
```

As you see, when I initialize this static member (i), I use the subclass name (Test2).
To my surprise, I tested this code with visual studio 2013 and it worked without error. But if I tried it with Netbeans(gcc11) under Linux and I got an hint error:
`unable to resolve the identifier i`
Then I compiled it, the error message is:
`error: ISO C++ does not permit ‘Test::i’ to be defined as ‘Test2::i’ [-fpermissive]`

Now if I change the protected into public for the `static int i` in the class Test, the error will disappear.

I am confused... This is my first time that I found two different results with gcc and vs.

Comment: How did you test it in visual studio?  was the test/code identical to what you did in netbeans?  I would think it would error, given that you are trying to publically access a private variable.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus  I am sure they are exactly the same code because i copy it. In fact I tried private and protected, both of them didn't work. ONLY public worked.

Comment: Clang still doesn't accept it after changing the access of `i` to `public`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition violates C++14 [class.static.data] §9.4.2/2. Emphasis mine:

> In the definition at namespace scope, the name of the static data
>   member shall be qualified by **its class name** using the `::`
>   operator.

A more recent version of GCC (on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)) behaves the same regardless of the qualifier. You can defeat the error on GCC with `-fpermissive`, but note that you're still only defining one object, belonging to the base class.

Comment: @Thomas I quoted the latest edition of the standard but the rule isn't at all new. The exact same words are in the exact same paragraph with the same section number in C++98.